# In "A Boy and His Dog", why were the inhabitants of Topeka wearing white-face?

Tags: a-boy-and-his-dog

In the movie [A Boy and His Dog](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072730/) (1975), Vic is lured to the "Downunder" which is revealed to contain a community modeled on some bizarre caricature of a town in the mid 20th century American mid-west. The inhabitants of that community are all wearing white-face make-up, for which there seemed to be no on-screen explanation. Does it have any explanation?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Boy_and_His_Dog_(1975_film)) (I know, that's why this is a comment) it's of a piece with the anachronistic attire and an indication of the control exerted by the ruling triumvirate.

Comment: I wonder if it is in the book also. I have no memory of the book. I can guess that some disease or other chronic condition affected the skin and so people started to wear heavy makeup and it eventually became the style. (Almost like Covid and masks -- Leiber wrote Coming Attraction decades before Covid predicting masks). So many fashion items have very unglamorous origins. Wigs (which I have heard various reasons for, one is shaving head for lice, other is worse) are but one example.

Comment: This question was answered in a review of the movie from 9 years ago I just listened to on Youtube -- all that either the director or ellison asked rhetorically was, How come Elizabethans wore ruffled collars? So just fashion. But I assumed that if some people wore makeup due to disfigurement (maybe from being underground or radiation) perhaps, like masks in Leiber's Coming Attractions, it becomes fashion as indeed almost happened I think with Covid -- many people as their eyes were accentuated looked better. (Black masks were a fashion choice I think.)